# Remove parent entity without its child

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 3 entities

```
public class Movie {


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<RoleCharacter> characters = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class Person {

    @OneToMany()
    private Set<RoleCharacter> moviesStarred = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
public class RoleCharacter {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Person actor;

    @ManyToOne
    private Movie movie;
}
```

I am trying to delete a Movie firstly, then RoleCharacter and don't remove a Person.
Was able to remove first 2 of them, but now, I don't know how to persist the Person without removing it.

Comment: If anybody is looking for a solution, this article helped so much https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-the-best-way-to-remove-entities-from-a-many-to-many-association/